# Adding to soapenv:Header in .NET C#

Tags: .net, web-services, soap

I'm required to write to the soapenv:Header as follows:

```
   <soapenv:Header>
  <head:Signature>somestringhere</head:Signature>
```

So far, I've been able to create a custom header - (there's plenty about this online) , but this doesn't create the required structure (I need the Signature element to be directly under the soapenv:Header element, rather than this:

```
  <soap:Header>
<CUSTOMHEADER xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <Signature>somestringhere</Signature>
</CUSTOMHEADER>
```

Does anyone know how I can add an element just under the default soap:Header element?

Many thanks